# Linq To Sql using AttachAll. DuplicateKeyException

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I searched for the answer on the website but I did not find one. I have the following problem ...

I'm trying to update multiple records in the database as follows:

```
  public void SaveJItem(List<DataForDespatcher> Jitem)
        {
             JitemsTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(Jitem.Where(i => i.Id ==0));
JitemsTable.AttachAll(Jitem.Where(i => i.Id != 0));
JitemsTable.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, Jitem);
JitemsTable.Context.SubmitChanges(); 

        }
```

The table is described as follows:

```
 [Table(Name = "tanks")] 
    public class DataForDespatcher
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true,AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    /*bla bla bla */
}
```

When I update I get the error:

> "DuplicateKeyException" in "JitemsTable.AttachAll(Jitem.Where(i => i.Id != 0));".

How do I correctly update the data?

ADD:
razor update form:

```
@inherits WebViewPage<IEnumerable<DomainModel.Entities.DataForDespatcher>>
/*bla bla bla*/
```

data controller save(get):

```
public ViewResult EditForDispatcher(int group)
        {
            var list = DataRep.JItems.Where(x => x.group == group).Select(x => x);
            return View(list);
        }
```

data controller save(post):

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditForDispatcher(List<DataForDespatcher> Jitem, string addNewOperation, string sendParam, string operations)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
 int group = DataRep.JItems.ToList().Max(x => x.group + 1);

                    if (Jitem.Any(x => x.group != 0))
                        foreach (var dataForDespatcher in Jitem)
                            dataForDespatcher.group = Jitem.Where(x=>x.group!=0).Select(x=>x.group).First(); 
                    else
                        foreach (var dataForDespatcher in Jitem)
                            dataForDespatcher.group = group; 
                    DataRep.SaveJItem(Jitem);
                }
         return View(Jitem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean exception is occur because you have both an updated and new items in List and the first in the list is not inserted item. I think, you must do somethong like this:

```
    JitemsTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(Jitem.Where(i => i.Id ==0));
    JitemsTable.AttachAll(Jitem.Where(i => i.Id != 0));
    JitemsTable.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, Jitem);
    JitemsTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I do not see that you have changed, still remained as I have ...http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_7790459_6293546.png

Comment: I don't use entity framework, but the code `if (Jitem.Select(x=>x.Id).First() == 0)
                JitemsTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(Jitem);` seems wrong, because Jitem can has both added and updated items, and  Jitem.Select(x=>x.Id).First() can return updated items Id which not 0.

Comment: then you will not help me? = (

Comment: same question I just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479800/attach-list-to-db-with-linq-to-sql  , has this changes at all in the past 2 years??? is there now a way to update/insert a list all at the same time?