# Attach list to db with linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

my problem is that I am trying to attach a `List<>` into a table in the database.  Some items in this List<> contain a Primary Key - these items should be treated as UPDATES to the database.  Some items do not have a primary key - these items should be INSERT into the db.

i Tried

```
  Context.myTable.AttachAll(myList, true);
  Context.myTable.AttachAll(myList, false);
  Context.myTable.AttachAll(myList);
```

all do not work. So then I do something like:

```
 var listFromDb =  Context.myTable.Where(x => myListOfIds.contains(x.primaryKey));
 foreach (var obj in myList)
 {
     if(obj.primaryKey > 0)
     {
        Context.myTable.Attach(obj, listFromDb.FirstOrDefault(x => x.primaryKey == obj.primaryKey);
     }
     else{
        Context.myTable.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
     }
     Context.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

there has to be an easier way then iterating through each item in the list and manually deciding weather or not to do Attach or Insert.  Is there something that I am missing here?

### EDIT

I found this same question from almost 2 years ago - [Linq To Sql using AttachAll. DuplicateKeyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330533/linq-to-sql-using-attachall-duplicatekeyexception)  ,  the answer in it is basically what my solution was.  With the new Entities 6 ,and all the new things added in the past 2 years is there now a way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Where's @JonSkeet when you need him?

Comment: I don't think Linq2SQL can use the primary key to "figure out" the states of your items.

Comment: @216 - it actually can , if you were to have a complete list of updates - it know , if you have a complete list of INSERTS - it knows,  why then can't it figure out on item by itme basis .  It seems like it checks the first item and assums all the rest are the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better solution but I think this will work fine:

```
foreach(var item in myList)
{
   if(item.Id > 0)
      context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;          
   else
      context.Table.Add(item);
}
```

And by this way you don't need to get all old items from the Database.

Comment: I'll try that out - it seems a bit cleaner

Comment: That assumes as a rule you have no record in the db with a primary key of 0 ... in programming terms this is called a "magic number" ... its usually considered bad practice. But if you can be sure that a key of 0 will never happen it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

You need to using ObjectContext though rather than DbContext i think so it depends how you built your context.